# Changin the charset of application Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I have a laravel app connected to a firebird DB
the charset of the DB is

> WIN1251
>   i set this in my .env like:

```
DB_CHARSET=WIN1251
```

but when i try to get data using #query_builder :

```
$product = DB::table('products')
    ->where('id', '=', 34)
    ->pluck(
        'name'
    );
```

I have an exception like:

```
Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded
```

Comment: Are you actually using `DB_CHARSET` in your `connections` array in `config/database.php`? By default, the setting is `'charset' => 'whatever',` (note that it doesn't reference an `.env` vairable, at least not in Laravel 5.4)

Comment: In my `config/databas.php` i have:             'charset'  => env('DB_CHARSET', 'WIN1251'),

Comment: Perfect; unfortunately, I haven't seen this error myself beyond missing the setting; hopefully someone else has seen it.

Comment: however, Thank you for your patience and attention

Comment: Have you tried setting the collation as well. I haven't seen this error either, but I feel like trying also a different option for collation might help.

Comment: Setting the collation for the DB,? or the laravel app?, for the DB, i can't, if in the app, how shoud i do that??